# How to modify element text in XML using python

Tags: python, xml

Would you give me some advice how to modify element text in XML using python?
if I want to insert other text in front of text of the first BBB element, which part should i change at the code below?

Please don't use fromstring and other modules(example lxml).

This is sample XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This</BBB> ----> the first BBB element
        </CCC>
        <CCC>  
            <BBB>is</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>test1</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This is test</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>
</data>
```

---

and it's code what i'm am trying below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse("C:\\test\\python test\\data_text.xml")
root = tree.getroot()                                                

for AAA in root.findall('AAA'):
    for CCC in AAA.findall('CCC'):
        for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB')[0]:
            BBB_text = '11111' + BBB.text
            print(BBB_text)

tree.write('C:\\test\\python test\\output.xml')
```

As far as i know, for BBB in CCC.findall('BBB')[0]:

### [0] means find only the first BBB, but i guess it's wrong.

and this is the result that i want.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>11111This</BBB> ----> the first BBB element
        </CCC>
        <CCC>  
            <BBB>is</BBB>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>test1</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>

    <AAA>
        <CCC>
            <BBB>This is test</BBB>
        </CCC>
    </AAA>
</data>
```

Comment: I see `BBB_text = '11111' + BBB.text`. Shouldn't it be `BBB.text = '11111' + BBB.text` ? Does `print(BBB_text)` prints the correct text ?

Comment: if i delete [0], no error when print(BBB_text) but it inserts '11111' to all texts of BBB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to iterate all the tags if you just need to update a single tag.

**Try:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()                                                

for AAA in root.findall('AAA'):
    if AAA.find('CCC'):
        BBB = AAA.find('CCC').find('BBB')
        BBB.text = '33333' + BBB.text

tree.write('C:\\test\\python test\\output.xml')
```

Comment: Does this do the right thing when there are multiple `<BBB>` to be found?

Comment: Updated snippet...Do you want just the first `BBB` tag or all first BBB tags?

Comment: Ah sorry. actually ultimatey i was trying to do for all first BBB tags.

Comment: Use the first snippet

Comment: Rakesh, i have one more question. your code looks great but what  does   BBB = AAA.find('CCC').find('BBB')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' this error mean

Comment: The error states that you do not have "CCC" tag in your element. You can use a if condition to check that Ex: `if AAA.find('CCC'): ....`

Comment: Oh i got understood. then i can use try and except.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh again. this is great for real. i remembered resolving other problem from you several days ago.

Answer (score 1):

`ElementTree` supports [a limited sub-set of XPath](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree#elementtree-xpath).

You can use

```
bbb = tree.find("./AAA/CCC/BBB")
if bbb:
    # do something
```

to get the very first such node in the tree, or

```
for bbb in tree.iterfind("./AAA/CCC/BBB"):
    # do something
```

to iterate over all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: [XPath answer from @Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585191/4298200) is way more elegant!

---

After some tests, it looks like `CCC.findall('BBB')[0]` works fine.
Since you want the first `BBB` tag within the document and not within each `AAA` tag, I would loose the `for` loops and modify the bit from my comment. I got this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse("data_text.xml")
root = tree.getroot()                                                

AAA = root.find('AAA')
CCC = AAA.find('CCC')
BBB = CCC.find('BBB')
BBB.text = '11111' + BBB.text
print(BBB.text)

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Seems to do the trick. You may need to check the validity of `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` to avoid crashes if the XML does not contain such tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this:

```
for a in tree:
    for c in a:
        for b in c:
            b.text = '11111' + b.text
            break
        break
    break
```