# How to modify a single property in xml file thorugh python loop without overwriting the whole file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, gis, arcgis

I have an xml file which looks like the one here [download xml file from here](https://easyupload.io/lgftzy). Its quite large so i uploaded it here. If the keyword "WMSServer" is searched for, it has a property definition within this file and within this property their is an attribute named "Enabled" and i want that to be set to True as currently it is set to False. How can i access that  property attribute and change its boolean value without overwriting the file. I tried doing it with this code but it overwrites the current files because of which i lose all the previous info which is what i don't want.

The original XML file before overwiting is here:
[original xml file](https://easyupload.io/n98e0k)

The changes xml file is here: [updated xml file](https://easyupload.io/qwe6hj)

**Python code**

```
output_draft=r"C:\Users\c\arcgis\image.xml"
doc = DOM.parse(output_draft)
typeNames = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
for typeName in typeNames:
    # Get the TypeName whose properties we want to modify.
    if typeName.firstChild.data == soe:
        extension = typeName.parentNode
        for extElement in extension.childNodes:
            # Enabled SOE.
            if extElement.tagName == 'Enabled':
                extElement.firstChild.data = 'true'
                print(extElement.firstChild.data, extElement)
                break
new_draft=output_draft
f = open(new_draft, 'w')     
doc.writexml( f )     
f.close()
del f,doc
```

Comment: If you use `'w'` mode, you will always overwrite the file. You can use `'a'` to append to the end of the file, but you will get incorrect structure (xml after xml, without common root). It's normal.

Comment: What info do you lose? You get xml, modify it and save it - so what is missing? It sounds like a normal behaviour and you just might want to add a counter or date to files to keep the history\

Comment: @h4z3i have added both xml files to my question. You can have a look. i am trying to create a map from this file. the first one shows a proper map but the second one just shows a black image. i think all information about data is lost while writing the file or it just writes a new file. i am not sure about it

Comment: On StackOverflow we like a thing called "Minimal Reproducible Example". Your full xml files are not minimal. You didn't even say before now what "map" you mean. That's the first time you say about some corrupted data... Earlier you only said about overwriting stuff with new content

Comment: @h4z3 i want to do something like this. with my file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584703/how-to-modify-element-text-in-xml-using-python.